# Delete pixels in selection from multiple layers at once in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections, image-editing

In Adobe Photoshop is there a way to have multiple layers selected and then delete pixels in a selection from them?

The closest I could think of is to add them to a group and apply a mask created from the selection, but my preference is to destructively delete.

Alternately perhaps there's a way to program an action to do this but I'm not certain.

Is there a native easy way or are there any recommendations on how to approach this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You forgot to mention what software you are using.  Most raster image editing software allows you to merge layers. Then you can make a selection and delete. Will that work for you?

Comment: @BillyKerr good catch - silly miss on my part - I've added it

Comment: Thanks.  But what about the rest of what I asked you?

Comment: @BillyKerr Unfortunately merging the layers won't work - thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it's possible. Perhaps surprisingly, this is actually a bit of an an unusual thing to do. What do you need it for? Pixel art?

Comment: @Wolff - yeah, an unusual thing to want to do, I agree. Doing non destructive editing is usually the best way to do anything in Photoshop.  I think this is possibly beginning to sound like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  I think it would be better if the OP said what exactly they want this for, so we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @BillyKerr The reason I need to be able to do it destructively so I can convert each individual layer to a selection and get its exact measurements from the info pane as this is a drawing that is to scale. Unfortunately when using masks, selecting the layer ignores the mask. Thanks

Comment: To be honest with you, Photoshop wouldn't be the best choice for making scale drawings.  It's really not designed for this, also I don't really think it's accurate enough for that purpose either. Photoshop is a photo editor. That is probably why you are having trouble (and why we think it's an odd thing to want to do).  Maybe you should consider using some CAD software.

Comment: photoshop does have this feature, sortof, it just works differently than your usecase needs. But the idea is that you but all your stuff in a group and mask the group. thisway its not destructive...

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to do it destructively for the above commented reason.

Answer (score 1):

Delete.. next layer below.. repeat...

or ....

<kbd>Del</kbd> then <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - repeat...

You could create and action so the shortcut to do both steps is merely a single F-key.

Or one *could* create an action to loop the steps and walk down layers - 
but it would be difficult to stop if you *didn't* want to delete from all layers below.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, you can select the pixels and then hit delete (or use a mask by making it black), select another layer from the menu that lists the layers without deselecting and do the same again for the next layer. That selection will then be affecting the layers you selected one by one. I'm also guessing you can do them all at once.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[example. sorry, seems I can't post it since it's too large.](https://i.imgur.com/Th60RfM.mp4)

Comment: Thanks - yeah that's what I ended up doing but the more layers the more manual effort this becomes - seems surprising they wouldn't have a way to do this more automatically but perhaps not